# autoincrement & decrement integer field are available in sqlite database?

Tags: android, sqlite, decrement

I am fetching my data with id which is Integer primary key or integer.

But after deleting any row...

After that if we make select query to show all.

But it will give force close because one id is missing.

I want that id can itself take `auto increment` & `decrement`.

when i delete a record at the end(i.g. id=7) after this i add a row then id must be 7 not 8. as same when i delete a row in middle(i.g. id=3) then all the row auto specify by acceding.

your idea can help me.

Comment: You can have a auto increment field in DB but what would you expect a behavior you delete a record at the end of your data set ? And in the middle ? Would you want all IDs to change ????

Comment: when i delete a record at the end(i.g. id=7) after this i add a row then id must be 7 not 8. as same when i delete a row in middle(i.g. id=3) then all the row auto specify by acceding.

Comment: Are you asking for the auto-increment field to fill in gaps left by deleting rows from the middle of the sequence?  That's not the way that it usually works.  Please clarify your question; it is very hard to understand what you are trying to ask.  (I understand English is not your native language.)

Comment: And in the middle ?????
That's  my point, there is no way the logic you want to apply to the ids of the last row can be applied to other rows, that's why Databases don't provide this kind of primary key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most systems with auto-incrementing columns keep track of the last value inserted (or the next one to be inserted) and do not ever reissue a number (give the same number twice), even if the last number issued has been removed from the table.

Judging from what you are asking, SQLite is another such system.

If there is any concurrency in the system, then this is risky, but for a single-user, single-app-at-a-time system, you might get away with:

```
SELECT MAX(id_column) + 1 FROM YourTable
```

to find the next available value.  Depending on how SQLite behaves, you might be able to embed that in the VALUES list of an INSERT statement:

```
INSERT INTO YourTable(id_column, ...)
    VALUES((SELECT MAX(id_column) + 1 FROM YourTable), ...);
```

That may not work; you may have to do this as two operations.  Note that if there is any concurrency, the two statement form is a *bad idea*<sup>TM</sup>.  The primary key unique constraint normally prevents disaster, but one of two concurrent statements fails because it tries to insert a value that the other just inserted - so it has to retry and hope for the best.  Clearly, a cell phone has less concurrency than, say, a web server so the problem is correspondingly less severe.  But be careful.

On the whole, though, it is best to let gaps appear in the sequence without worrying about it.  It is usually not necessary to worry about them.  If you must worry about gaps, don't let people make them in the first place.  Or move an existing row to fill in the gap when you do a delete that creates one.  That still leaves deletes at the end creating gaps when new rows are added, which is why it is best to get over the "it must be a contiguous sequence of numbers" mentality.  Auto-increment guarantees uniqueness; it does not guarantee contiguity.

Comment: @ Jonathan Leffler your thought is absolutely right but what the issue of mine is ahter the remove the row how can i fetch data by id?

Comment: @Sitanshu: you can always fetch by `id` when you know the value to fetch, but you won't be guaranteed that every `id` value will fetch a row (because the value might have been deleted). It is really quite tricky to ensure that a table only contains contiguous numbers; that's why the DBMS does not try to do it. If you do enough work, and the DBMS supports triggers etc, you might be able to get things sorted out, but the effort involved is usually too great for the benefit. So, why do you need fully dense (contiguous) packing of ID values? What algorithm would reassign numbers after a deletion?

Comment: the algorithm after deletion is not made up yet. I think the fetch data from id is risky. so i try the different solution. thanks for suggestion.